# Resistance in rear hub?

Tags: maintenance, hub

I bought a new mid-range hybrid bike (Pinnacle Lithium), and for the first couple of weeks it was an absolute pleasure to ride. Then I went on holiday for two weeks, leaving it in a shed in the heat (if it's relevant). When I came back, it felt like the bike has slowed down. I'm pretty sure it did, because I have another bike that I still ride on the same set of gears, whereas with this one, I kind of went down from speed 6 to speed 3-4 at the back on the average ride.

It feels like some mild, but noticeable resistance on both pedalling and the free ride. I've checked that the brakes don't touch the rims, re-lubricated the chain, made sure the tyre pressure is ok - the problem is still there.

Could it be something like overtightened bearings in the rear hub or grease drying up there? Please tell me I'm not just imagining it :)

Comment: My bikes are always slower when i come back from holiday too.  Nothing at all to do with excessive beer and cake consumption ;-)

Comment: I'd suggest giving it a normal maintenance - inflate tyres to pressure, clean and lube chain, check the wheels are spinning freely and that there is no brake drag or frame rub.

Comment: Could the bike have been damaged by a person or animal or perhaps a vehicle manoevering ?  Has someone else ridden it in the meantime ?

Comment: This is a good question but, honestly, when your brand-new bike doesn't work right, the first thing to do is to take it back to the shop and get them to fix it. If it just needs adjustment, they should do it for free. If it needs more than that, the warranty covers problems caused by defective parts; if you did happen to make things worse trying to fix them, that wouldn't be covered.

Comment: I did take it to the shop for a six-week service, they think it's fine. But I suspect they didn't look into the hub...

Answer (score 1):

Hold the wheel off the ground.

Spin it.

See how quickly it slows down.

Compare to the front wheel. If it's the same then "you're imagining it".

Make sure you have more than 50psi tyre pressure (20psi and it will feel like treacle)

Next time spend some of your holiday outside of bars and restaurants.

Comment: They are never 'the same', there is always significantly more drag in the rear hub (I assume due to the freewheel).

Comment: It does slow down faster than I'd like.

Comment: Andy makes a good point. Compare to another bikes back wheel might be more accurate. If you do it at the bike shop, they can't argue (as easily)